# How can I draw a line indicating today's/current date in google visualization

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on a Project Dashboard and have a list of 10 of projects listed on a timeline using: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline but I couldn't find anything in which I could draw a line or something to indicate current date to show the progress of each project so far.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Make the end date for the active project `new Date()` (returns current date and time).